# HTTP 404 error: (/SpringMVC/) ressource unavailable

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-mvc

I've installed:

```
-eclipse Indigo 3.7,
-JDK 1.7 in /usr/lib/jvm` and,
-Tomcat 7
-Spring framework 2.5.6
```

I'm trying to do a tutorial [found here:](http://www.lalitbhatt.com/Spring+MVC&)

For that I have created a «`dynamic web project`» done with «spring MVC framework». I tried to run it doing «`Run on server`» but I got an «`HTTP 404 error: (/SpringMVC/) ressource unavailable`». I really don't know what am I missing. Thank you in advance for any help.

These are the librairies I had initially included in the project:

```
-jakarta-commons/commons-logging.jar
-mysql-connector-java-5.1.18
-j2ee/jstl.jar
-log4j/log4j-1.2.14.jar
-jakarta-taglibs/standard.jar
-dist/spring.jar
-dist/modules/spring-webmvc.jar
```

I've just added the `spring-web.jar` library.

This is the new error message I am having:

```
nov. 22, 2011 7:48:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\MinGW\bin\;C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\local\bin\;C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0\bin\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse;;.
    nov. 22, 2011 7:48:16 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringMVC' did not find a matching property.
    nov. 22, 2011 7:48:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    nov. 22, 2011 7:48:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    nov. 22, 2011 7:48:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 571 ms
    nov. 22, 2011 7:48:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    nov. 22, 2011 7:48:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.21
    nov. 22, 2011 7:48:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [C:\Users\cProg\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpringMVC\]
    nov. 22, 2011 7:48:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing log4j from [C:\Users\cProg\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpringMVC\WEB-INF\log4j.xml]
    nov. 22, 2011 7:48:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    nov. 22, 2011 7:48:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springapp'
    nov. 22, 2011 7:48:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    nov. 22, 2011 7:48:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    nov. 22, 2011 7:48:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 1653 ms
```

I've 4 xml files:

```
-applicationContext.xml
-web.xml
-springapp-servlet.xml
-log4j.xml
```

Their source code are:

`applicationContext.xml`

```
<!--applicationContext.xml-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- The Dao class -->
<bean id="studentDao" class="com.oyejava.springmvc.StudentJdbcDao">
    <property name="simpleJdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
</bean>

<!-- Template class to access JDBC code -->
<bean id="jdbcTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Configuration for the data source -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <!-- <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />-->
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306" />
    <!-- <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost" />-->
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

`log4j.xml`

```
<!--log4j.xml-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="info" />
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="rolling-file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/JMEAR.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10KB" />
        <!-- Keep one backup file -->
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="4" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %l - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="warn"/>
    </logger>

    <!-- 
         everything of spring was set to "info" but for class 
         PropertyEditorRegistrySupport we want "debug" logging 
    -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrySupport">
        <level value="info"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.flex.samples.*">
        <level value="info"/>
    </logger>
    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <!--<appender-ref ref="console" />
        -->
        <appender-ref ref="rolling-file" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

`springapp-servlet.xml`

```
<!--springapp-servlet.xml-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <value>messages</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="studentListController"
        class="com.oyejava.springmvc.StudentListController">
        <property name="studentDao" ref="studentDao" />
    </bean>

    <!-- command class and command name are used to retrieve and set the 
        value as name value pair in HttpRequest and Response. The form view
        tells that when the request comes for this Controller than which
        form to display in which user input can be taken. -->

    <bean id="studentCreateController"
        class="com.oyejava.springmvc.StudentCreateController">
        <property name="studentDao" ref="studentDao" />
        <property name="formView" value="createStudent" />
        <property name="commandName" value="student" />
        <property name="commandClass" value="com.oyejava.springmvc.Student" />
        <property name="validator">
            <bean class="com.oyejava.springmvc.StudentValidator" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="loggingInterceptor"
        class="com.oyejava.springmvc.LoggingInterceptor" />

    <bean id="simpleUrlMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref local="loggingInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/studentList.htm">
                    studentListController
                </prop>
                <prop key="/createStudent.htm">
                    studentCreateController
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

`web.xml`

```
<!--web.xml-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>

    <!-- log4j configuration in web.xml -->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
    <!-- /log4j configuration in web.xml END -->

    <!-- The parameter tells about the location of configuration XML. Usually
    all the data access beans and service layer beans are kept here. You can register
    more than one XML here. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- The listener is reponsible for building the spring container. It looks for
        all configuration XML as defined by parameter contextConfigLocation and also looks 
        for a configuration which is named as Dispatch Servlet name. In this case it will
        be named as springapp-servlet.xml -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Dispatcher Servlet which traps all the request targeted for Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Mapping for the request. It can be anything -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`

seems you did not include the spring-web.jar dependency to the classpath (in WEB-INF/lib).

Comment: Hi Gabriel thank you for your answer. I've edited my initial message with the new error message.

Comment: NEVER include servlet-api.jar in your webapp class path.

Comment: Does the problem comes from what is expressed in the second line of the error message? If yes how to fix it please?

`Infos: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib`

Comment: Hi @Gabriel,

I have included the servlet-api.jar in the path because there some sevlet in the project.

About the inclusion of libraries, should properties->Java Build path->add jar and also copy them inton WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: Ensure the required libraries are included in the Deployment Assembly (project properties->Deployment assembly), and that servlet-api is not there.

Comment: I've updated the error message. Anyone could give a hint please?